# Making 3 divs equidistant. They are within a div, within a div. On a parallax webpage

Tags: center

Hi to all,

I'm trying to make 3 divs equidistant from each other. The DIV width is determined by the IMG file in it.

I have succeeded in making a container div 80% width of the page and is centered.

However, the DIVs inside this are equidistant to each other (for as far I can see) but **do not** center themselves *according to the div they are in*.

HTML:

```
<div class="slide" id="slide5" data-slide="5" data-stellar-background-ratio="0"> 

<div class="slide5_wrapper">

    <div class="slide5_recd2011">
        <a href="images/foto2011/_MG_0934.JPG" data-lightbox="RECD2011" title="Lezingen"><img src="images/RECD2011_thumbnail.png"></a>
        <a href="images/foto2011/_MG_0972.jpg" data-lightbox="RECD2011" title="Lunch"></a>
    </div>        

    <div class="slide5_recd2012">
        <a href="images/foto2011/_MG_0934.JPG" data-lightbox="RECD2012" title="Lezingen"><img src="images/RECD2011_thumbnail.png"></a>
    </div>

    <div class="slide5_recd2013">
        <a href="images/foto2011/_MG_0934.JPG" data-lightbox="RECD2013" title="Lezingen"><img src="images/RECD2011_thumbnail.png"></a>
    </div>

</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
.slide5_wrapper{
margin: 0 auto;
width:80%;
position: relative;
max-height:80%;
top:10%;
text-align:justify;

}



.slide5_recd2011, .slide5_recd2012, .slide5_recd2013 {
margin: 10px;
height:auto;
border-radius:15px;
vertical-align: top;
display:inline-block;
}

#slide5_wrapper:after {
content: '';
width:100%;
display:inline-block;
}
```

Excuse me for my horrible use of terminology (wrappers /containters w/e) just want this to work.

I'm not a real website coder, just trying to learn and I have this project I have taken on while not being too qualified for it (it's a temporary non-corporate website and not going to be my business so I'm not destroying the work field or anything).

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Here is the [link](http://css-tricks.com/equidistant-objects-with-css/) with explanation, here is the working [sample](http://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/nfyGk).

```
#slide5_wrapper{
text-align: justify;
}

#slide5_wrapper:after{
content:'';
width:100%;
display:inline-block;
}

#slide5_wrapper div{
display: inline-block;
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

What's just about this:

```
.slide5_recd2012{
    width: 33%;
    float:left;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: /*some padding you need */ 0;
}
```

?

Comment: This seems to work for now. I am not sure if it will work on other screen resolutions properly but for now, thanks a lot!

Comment: Well, the elements are stretched with 33% definition, so they must work. The only problems you can experience if you make paddings too big and have the window size too small. But you always can test it with the window/container resizing. (Even, with using any browser DOM tools).

Comment: Worked it out, thanks! Had to change the width to 30% considering I had some margin between them but they fit nicely now.